# Tools and process for designing a Spark skin

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-spark

I come from the web development background where the process of skinning a website normally looks like this:

1. Designer creates a design in Photoshop
2. The design is transferred into HTML + CSS using the following heuristics:

   - Where possible, use the CSS toolbox to create borders, background colors and the like
   - In case of more complicated shapes (e.g. gradients, rounded corners etc.), use raster sprites

Now, I'm working on skinning an app done in Adobe Flex and I'm wondering what the best approach should be. ActionScript's vector graphics capabilities are a lot more extensive than "vector graphics" (borders, background colors) done in CSS, so perhaps creating a design in Photoshop isn't the best idea.

Should I ask my designer to create the design in Illustrator instead, hoping that it will be possible to transfer most of the advanced shapes (like button gradients, rounded corners etc.) into a Spark skin "natively" as vector graphics as opposed to embedding those as bitmaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call button gradients, rounded corners, etc. advanced shapes then indeed I would go for the Illustrator approach. These are all shapes that translate easily and cheaply into vector graphics/code. For this kind of graphics, vectors are usually much better for memory and performance.
Illustrator can export directly to FXG. Just make sure to tell your designer to anchor his drawings in the top left corner when he does the export so you don't have to deal with offsets.

If however your graphics become more complex (a drawing, or maybe some complex symbol) you're better of embedding it as a bimap graphic.

As a last note: Adobe previously had a product called Catalyst that was supposed to address the designer/developer workflow for Flex apps, but they discontinued it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I understand it correctly that theoretically, I also have the option of trying to manually replicate a design done in Photoshop using vectors in Flex?

Comment: Illustrator also has ability to export images to swf.

Comment: Using the Illustrator -> export to FXG approach is very powerful. I found the FXG (xml markup) created by Illustrator to be a little verbose, and would often write the markup myself (or cleanup the markup created by Illustrator). FXG is precompiled, so it can be much more performant than importing Illustrator assets to the SWF format.

Comment: @jamix Yes indeed. As a matter of fact that is how I usually work. But you'll have to have a thorough idea of what you're doing and lots of attention to detail or you will not keep your designer happy ;)